# "Can't sign in" & "Please try again. If the problem continues, you might need to restart your phone" error when downloading new apps from store

Tags: 8.1, store, lumia-520

**Info**: I have a Nokia Lumia 520 running Windows 8.1 (OS version: 8.10.12393.890) and I'm getting a really weird error that I can't find a solution for, I'm not sure if it can be fixed. I'm not sure when it started exactly, but it's been this way at least a month (never used the store much so I didn't care at the time). The Store used to work fine with no problems, and this just started happening randomly and I don't believe I made any changes that would cause this.

**Problem:**
When I go to the store and try to download any app, I get an error with the title "Can't sign in" and the body "Please try again. If the problem continues, you might need to restart your phone".

**Things I've tried:**

- Re-synced my Microsoft account through the phone settings.
- Reset my Microsoft password
- Made sure all my info was correct on my Microsoft account.
- Triple checked my Region and Date/Time were correct (trust me I really checked)
- Made my Windows phone a trusted device
- Made sure I had no Phone updates or App updates pending
- Looked through all my Microsoft account settings to see if anything looked weird, and I don't see anything that would limit my phone from downloading apps.
- Soft reset
- Hard reset

After the hard reset didn't work I just gave up, I don't see what else it could be. An interesting note is that after I hard reset my phone almost all my backed up apps downloaded perfectly from the store automatically no fuss, except for 2 apps (which I can't see which apps they are) with error (805a0194). I don't really care about these apps, I just want to download new ones.

The store on my Windows 10 desktop computer can download apps fine, so it leads me to believe it is a problem with my phone and not my account, but I did a hard reset which makes me believe it is my account and not my phone. I'm not tech illiterate but I know nothing about phones, so I'm at a lost with what else I could possibly do. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I tried to download an app today and it worked. I don't know what exactly fixed it, so if anyone else runs into this problem do everything I listed in the OP. And make sure to wait a couple days, whatever fixed it took time.

Answer (score 1):

**In a nutshell:**

This error code seems to the problem with the corresponding apps rather than your Microsoft account or your phone. Contact the app developers.

**Details and explanation:**

Refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7777955/5407188) here in Stack overflow. It is said,

> The 8 makes it a fatal error. The 0x5a is the 'facility code', an
> indication what component caused the error.
>
> .....
>
> 0x194 = 404. The Universal Internet File-not-found Error Code.
> Something wrong with the url you use.

It is worth to note that this answer has been accepted by the developer who asked it.

As you said other apps download just fine ecept the two apps, you must contact the app developers.

*My guess :* These apps must have been Windows phone 8.1 apps and the URL mapping to windows 10 store must have met some error.

It is upto the developers to resolve it. There is nothing you can do.

Comment: I don't mind that those 2 specific apps didn't install, but I can go to any app in the store and try to download it, I will still get a "Can't sign in" error. Maybe those apps need to be fixed by the developers, but that wasn't my problem.

Comment: @user3418126 You said all other apps are downloading fine, when you said *store works fine except for the two apps* Are they showing any error too?

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear. When I said the store worked fine, I meant on my computer. I mentioned this to show there was no problem with my account preventing me from downloading (at least from my computer).

The apps I already had before the hard reset also downloaded fine, but no other apps would. When I try to download other apps, I get the error described above ("Please sign in")